# How to use neural network to label data in an interval

Tags: neural-networks, keras

My input is one integer, and it should give me 1 if it's the good interval, otherwise 0, such as:

[image: formula]

Is this problem solvable with a neural network ? If so, how ?

I tried something using Keras but couldn't make it work, the new values predicted aren't right:

```
import sys
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import numpy as np

# Function to get the reward
def getReward(value):
    if value < 10 or value > 20:
        return 1
    return 0

# Function to test the results
def test(x):
    X = [[(x-50)/100]]
    print("{} normalized is {}".format(x, X))
    Y = model.predict_on_batch(np.asarray(X))
    print("Value {} predicted {} instead of {}".format(x, Y[0][0], getReward(x)))

# Creating model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=1, init='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')

# Generating data
X = [[x] for x in range(0,100)]
Y = [getReward(x[0]) for x in X]
# Normalization of input data
X = np.asarray([[(x[0]-50)/100] for x in X])
print("Normalized is {}".format(X))

model.fit(X, np.asarray(Y).reshape(-1, 1), batch_size=32, epochs=5000, verbose = 1)

command = ""
while command != "stop":
    try:
        data = input('Enter a value: ')
        if(data == "stop"):
            break
        test(float(data))
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not checked your code but an (appropriate) neural network can fit your indicator function easily.  I am not a Keras expert but it looks like you have tanh activation in the hidden layer and linear output, which I think is not a good choice here.  Perhaps you can try with sigmoid/logistic activation.  The following is a single hidden layer of (only size 3) with sigmoid activation (a=2,b=5; red line is fitted; non-integer data is including in training;)

[image]

Note that you would not expect an exact fit.

One consideration is whether a neural network is the most appropriate for your problem.  You may wish to simply estimate $a$ and $b$ with another (perhaps more classical) method.